# Basis of matrices with a variable

Tags: matrices, determinant, groebner-basis

So I have these bunch of matrices I want to find the value of a to find the basis

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 2  \\ 
        1 & -2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        1 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a  \\
        2 & -2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a  \\
        1 & -1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

What I could do is write them in a different way

$$A\pmatrix{2\\2\\1\\-2}+B\pmatrix{0\\0\\1\\1}+C\pmatrix{1\\a\\2\\-2}+D\pmatrix{1\\a\\1\\-1}$$

Now I can find the RREF but since those are letter "A"s i dont know what to do.
Someone told me I should use the determinant test.
How do I use the determinant test in this situation?

Comment: Are you trying to find the value of $a$ that makes the collection above a basis? The columns form a basis iff $\det$ of the columns is non zero.

Comment: A slightly simpler way would be to notice that $v_1,..,v_4$ is a basis iff $v_1,v_2,v_3, v_3-v_4$ is also a basis. This eliminates one of the $a$s.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question?

> I want to find the set of values for $a$ that would make this a basis

? Anyways, $a$ is just a real number; don't be intimidated by the fact it's a variable rather than a decimal constant. Just do what you would normally do to test if those four vectors form a basis.

The only real complication is things like the fact $a$ is not a non-zero variable, so, e.g., you can't divide by $a$. If you get to a point where it matters whether $a$ is zero or not, you'd have to split the domain into the domain where $a$ is zero and the domain where $a$ is nonzero and treat the two cases separately.

Answer (score 0):

Put up your vectors as columns in a matrix. These are linearly independent (and thus a basis) iff the determinant of this matrix is nonzero.
You should be able to solve this with a quadratic equation in a.