# Basis of vectors with a variable

Tags: matrices, determinant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basis of matrices with a variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291603/basis-of-matrices-with-a-variable)
>   [Basis of a $2 \times 2$ matrix with trace $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291711/basis-of-a-2-times-2-matrix-with-trace-0)

So I have these bunch of matrices I want to find the value of variable "a" to find the basis for M2x2 using determinant test

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 2  \\ 
        1 & -2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        1 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a  \\
        2 & -2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a  \\
        1 & -1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

What I could do is write them in a different way

$$A\pmatrix{2\\2\\1\\-2}+B\pmatrix{0\\0\\1\\1}+C\pmatrix{1\\a\\2\\-2}+D\pmatrix{1\\a\\1\\-1}$$

Now I can find the RREF but since those are letter "A"s i dont know what to do.
Someone told me I should use the determinant test.
How do I use the determinant test in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Solve

$ det
\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 0 &  1 &  1 \\
   2 & 0 &  a &  a \\
   1 & 1 &  2 &  1 \\
  -2 & 1 & -2 & -1
 \end{pmatrix} \neq 0$.